# Mssql_query can return values after db close, while sqlsrv_query cannot

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv, php-mssql

I am new to backend developer, so this might be dumb if i am wrong in the begining.I found out that sqlsrv and mssql ways of handling db are different. For example, mssql_query can return data after db close, but sqlsrv_query cannot. 
For example:

```
$query = "select branchname, id from Branch";
$rs = $this->db->query($query);
$this->db->close();
Return $rs;
```

This code can pass values to the controllers in mssql_driver ,but cannot pass to controllers in sqlsrv_driver. After i remove the db close function, it works in sqlsrv.So i think that these 2 are different.Or am i wrong? Please teach me

Answer (score 0):

You are right, can be read here -> [SQLSRV->Close](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-close.php) and here -> [MSSQL->Close](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-close.php)

The SQLSRV close method releases resourses associated with the connection and MSSQL does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have understand now